# AngularJS css animation + done callback

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I am using AngularJS and would like to get notified when an animation is done. I know this can be done with javascript-defined animations like this `myApp.animation(...)`, but I am curious if I can do this without javascript.

**Question:** Is it possible to use angular ***ng-enter*** and ***ng-leave*** css-transitions, and specify a done callback? I guess the `animationend` event is fired, so there should be a way to do this.

I have this:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-if="item" class="myDiv"> {{ item.name }} </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myDiv.ng-enter {...}
.myDiv.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {...}
.myDiv.ng-leave {...}
.myDiv.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {...}
```

And I want to call `myDone()` when the animation has finished (i.e. after the `ng-enter-active` class is removed).

Comment: Yeah, that event works. I suggest you reading this: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/transition/transition.js That is a factory to run animations and be informed when they end. Learn the idea and try to apply it to your use case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can, using the [`$animate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate) service, which would usually be done in a custom directive. A simple case of animation would be to animate an element in some way on click. Say, for example to remove an element on click, with an animation specified using .ng-leave, passing a callback

```
app.directive('leaveOnClick', function($animate) {
  return {
    scope: {
      'leaveOnClick': '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.leaveOnClick = scope.leaveOnClick || (function() {});
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          $animate.leave(element, scope.leaveOnClick);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

which could be used like:

```
<div class="my-div" leaveOnClick="done()">Click to remove</div>
```

With CSS to fade the element out:

```
.my-div.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
}
.my-div.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

You can see [the above animation in action at this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5r9tBmqCdYO9st7MlKUj?p=preview).

However, ngIf doesn't have any hooks to pass a callback in  that I know of, so you'll have to write your own directive. What follows is a description of [a modified version of ngIf](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqwAPyPhpeCGOGO5gXkF?p=preview), originally copied from the [ngIf source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.5/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L3), and renamed to `animatedIf`. It can be used by:

```
<div class="my-div" animated-if="shown" animated-if-leave-callback="leaveDone()" animated-if-enter-callback="enterDone()" >Some content</div>
```

The way it works is that it uses a manual watcher to react to changes of the expression passed to `animated-if`. The key differences to the original ngIf are the addition of a 'scope' parameter to pass the callbacks in:

```
scope: {
  'animatedIf': '=',
  'animatedIfEnterCallback': '&',
  'animatedIfLeaveCallback': '&'
},
```

and then modifying the calls to `$animate.enter` and `$animate.leave` to call these callbacks after the animation:

```
var callback = !oldValue && $scope.animatedIfEnterCallback ? $scope.animatedIfEnterCallback : (function() {});
$animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element, callback);

$animate.leave(block.clone, ($scope.animatedIfLeaveCallback || (function() {})));
```

The enter one is a bit more complicated to not call the callback on initial loading of the directive. Because of the `scope` parameter, this directive creates an isolated scope, which it then uses when transcluding the contents. So another change that is required is to create and use a scope as a child from the `$parent` scope of the directive: the line

```
 childScope = $scope.$new();
```

must be changed to

```
 childScope = $scope.$parent.$new();
```

You can [see the full source of the modified ngIf directive in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqwAPyPhpeCGOGO5gXkF?p=preview). This has only been tested extremely briefly.

There may well be a simpler way of doing this, maybe by not recreating the ngIf directive fully, but creating a directive with template that uses the original ngIf with some wrapper divs, such as

```
template: '<div><div ng-if="localVariable"><div ng-transclude></div></div></div>'
```

Comment: Thanks!! However, your animated-if does not work with data-binding inside the animated-if. See this [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wAJKCMtagT6db8iItK2w?p=preview)

Comment: You're right: I have edited the post and links to Plunker that allows data binding to the original scope.

Comment: FYI you could use angular.noop instead of (function() {}). Save you 3 characters :)

Comment: @MichalCharemza 
Following your answer, it seems I have a problem with `$scope.$apply` not being used. So, for example, when I'm changing the controller inside of the callbacks, the view does not change. I'm currently using constructions like `$scope.$apply(function() {ctrl.value = true;});` inside my callback to solve this.

Comment: I have updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GZTpcL80mqIGCBaBHPXT?p=preview) to support controller changes, using `childScope.$apply` I'm not exactly sure the script is totally fine, but providing it as a suggestion for solution.