# ng-repeat animation finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that I can use [`$animate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) service to call a method when I manually perform animation to any elemnt (like what suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20836688/2407522)), however i want to detect when `ng-repeat` animation finishs.

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="cat in cats">
  <div class="cat-container card">
    <div class="cat-header">
      <h4 ng-click="setActive($index)">{{cat.title}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-body">
      <div ng-if="cat.img" class="cat-img">
        <img ng-src="{{cat.img}}">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-cats-container">
        <div class="sub-cat" ng-animate ng-repeat="subcat in cat.subcats | filter: getSearch($index)">
          <div class="cat-img">
            <img ng-src="{{subcat.img}}" alt="{{subcat.title}}" width="150px" height="70px">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**animations**

```
.sub-cat.ng-move,
.sub-cat.ng-enter,
.sub-cat.ng-leave {
    transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) .5s;
}

.sub-cat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.sub-cat.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.sub-cat.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 70px;
}

.sub-cat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.sub-cat.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get a callback for `ng-enter` and `ng-move` using the `$animate:close` event

For example (using angularJS 1.3.4):

```
myApp.directive('subCat', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('$animate:close', function() {
            // This will fire after every CSS or JavaScript animation is complete
            console.log('$animate:close');
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is a fiddle illustrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/4wt4nr6s/

While it works fine for `ng-enter` and `ng-move`, this seems not to work for `ng-leave`, this is a bug that angularJS has yet to solve: 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6049