# Angular ng-view animation callback

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning angular and I have a question about the animations between `ng-view` templates.

When I click on the template link, the current template and the new one (clicked one) keeps animating **simultaneously**, making the content after the `ng-view` jump down for both old and new templates height.

This is my index.html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#/">View 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">View 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

page.html (template)

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="center"><!-- this div centers the content horizontally,
                             it has a fixed value (with margin:0 auto) which
                             will change with media querys -->

        <h1>view</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.ng-enter, .ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.ng-enter-active{
    opacity: 1;
}

.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}

.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.page>div.center{
    width: 500px; /* fixed width, this value will change in media queryes*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[New plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7c9bOqrP2VNonsUbCsGx?p=preview)

On start *View 1* is shown. How to make that when I click on *View 2* to first fade out *View 1*, and then fade in *View 2*?

Now when I click *View 2* it start the fadein simultaneously with *View 1* fading out, making the content after `ng-view` jump for both templates height, which I don't want.

As @Dabbiemiller suggested, using `display:inline-block` suits but then it breaks my horizontal centering - [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/2nJrtogE8GtiM8so4fAu/preview)

Comment: simply, you could just put a delay property in the transition: http://plnkr.co/edit/EcI5kBxo4pXCsh3th8Jh?p=info

Comment: @Dabbiemiller the content after `ng-view` is still jumping in your plunker.

Comment: @Vucko try giving the ng-view div a fixed size. or maybe put it in a fixed-size container

Comment: That could be a bad idea...;)

Comment: Here I fixed the positioning too http://plnkr.co/edit/EcI5kBxo4pXCsh3th8Jh?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
.ng-enter, .ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

with the following code

```
.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

you don't need to make animation on both events(enter/leave) you can make just on enter and it wont make the simultaneous animation it will hide the first view immediately and then animate the second .

http://plnkr.co/edit/iVSRrg9nBaDTtHUZcDDu

if you need one animation after another you need a callback. To avoid repetition you can find the answer here:

[AngularJS css animation + done callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828681/angularjs-css-animation-done-callback)

Comment: +1 this will work. However, can you make an example with JavaScript and callbacks?

Answer (score 3):

Take this: http://plnkr.co/edit/EcI5kBxo4pXCsh3th8Jh?p=preview

```
<div ng-view style="display:inline-block;"></div>
```

And as said in the comments, add delay to your transitions:

```
.ng-enter{
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease 1s;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease 1s;
  transition: all 2s ease 1s;
}

.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

**Edit:**
After the comment from Vucko, saying my solution isn't working by him, because of an inner div that has some fixed width, I've suggested a new solution [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1IKXLq4fvgrwLNIhYDHn) , with `position:absolute;`.

Comment: Your plunker works but I have a little different situation. In my template I have an inner div that has some fixed width (so that it is centred within the page). [See the new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bxiIQDMpgqRRgEWrr4Nf?p=preview). Note that I removed your `display:inline-block` from `ng-view` - it wasn't working like in your plunker.

Comment: Then use position: absolute, like in here :http://plnkr.co/edit/1IKXLq4fvgrwLNIhYDHn

Comment: It breaks if there is more content- [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8UL7a3ORmv3LD4JXcPj3?p=info)