# Don't ng-show element until ng-hide CSS transition is complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

Simple question, but I'm having implementation troubles. If I have the following DOM setup:

```
<h1 class="fade" ng-repeat="child in parent.children" ng-show="parent.activeChild== child ">@{{ child.title }}</h1>
```

When the `activeChild` property of the `parent` model changes, how can I fade out the currently active child, **before** the model changes, and then fade in the newly active child **post-change**.

I have it working roughly, with just CSS transitions using this:

```
.fade.ng-hide-add {
    transition:opacity 1s ease;
}

.fade.ng-hide-remove {
    transition:opacity 1s ease 1s;
}

.fade.ng-hide-add {
    opacity:1;

    &.ng-hide-add-active {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

.fade.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity:0;

    &.ng-hide-remove-active {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

But, this ends up producing [this problem (Plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/m9nOmJoKBNJl8uiCAghl?p=preview):

[image: Gif]

Essentially, I want to chain my animation. I've tried reading the [ng-animate docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), but I'm having trouble the syntax necessary to deliver the effect I want.

I've seen the Angular docs have something like this:

```
app.animation('.fade', [function() {
    return {
        addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
        },
        removeClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
        }
    };
}]);
```

- What is `className`? Is it the class I want to apply while fading in/out? The class I'm expecting?
- What is `doneFn` meant to be? I assume it's a function that's run once the animation is complete? What goes in there?
- What do I do in the `addClass` and `removeClass` function then, if I already have a `doneFn`?

#### The Goal

I'd like to generate a working animation directly using Angular's ngAnimate module, with either CSS or JS. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could try adding a delay to the `.ng-enter` transition CSS that is the same as the fade-out transition time for `.ng-leave`, eg `transition: opacity .5s .5s`. There shouldn't be any need to write any JS for this

Comment: Will that not result in the the second element appearing first, then the first fading out? I don't want to see both elements simultaneously. Even if opacity is 0, the element will still take up space, yes?

Comment: why not building an angular controller which manages that stuff?

Comment: Because I don't have any idea how to do that.

Comment: If you're working with AngularJS you'll want to learn how to write controllers and directives. There's a huge amount of free training available, and the power you'll wield is fantastic. In this case, a watch directive with timeouts for your animations may work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have clarified, I know how to use angular controllers and directives, but I have no clue how to use their animation library. I've read the docs a couple of times now and I can't get my head around it.

Comment: How about `position: absolute` on the entering / leaving element?

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle with current issue.

Comment: @Phil just tried, that causes quite a mess, ha. I'm not really wanting a workaround solution - I'd like an answer which directly tackles Angular's JS/CSS animation module head on.

Comment: @EchoLogic I had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482101/angular-ng-view-animation-callback).

Comment: I think you should specify that you want a solution that **guarantees** the synchonisation of animations. A timeout can only ever be an approximation as it depends on system time availability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why do you use a separate `<h1>` for each heading. You can use a single `<h1>` tag to show your heading.

I have created a demo for your problem and I have successfully done your requirement.

**Updated**

Note, codes are edited to use `ngAnimate` module. When you use `ngAnimate` module, it will create a class `.ng-hide` when you hide an element,

Here is the controller for your app,

```
app2.controller("testController", ["$scope", "$timeout", function ($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.heading = {};
    $scope.heading.show = true;

    $scope.parent = {};
    $scope.parent.children = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    $scope.parent.activeChild = "A";

    $scope.changeHeading = function (child) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.parent.activeChild = child;
            $scope.heading.show = true;
        }, 1000);

    }
}]);
```

And your html page should be look like this,

```
<div ng-controller="testController">
    <h1 class="myAnimateClass" ng-show="heading.show" ng-class="{fadeIn : heading.fadeInModel==true, fadeOut : heading.fadeOutModel}"> {{parent.activeChild}} </h1>
    <p ng-repeat="child in parent.children" ng-click="heading.show = false;changeHeading(child)">{{child}}</p>
</div>
```

And I have used CSS3 to implement the fade in and fade out animation,

```
.myAnimateClass {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    opacity:1;
}

.myAnimateClass.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**Explanation**

To achieve your requirement, I have used `ng-class` and `$timeout` in angularJS.

You can see that, I have only one `<h1>` tag to display your heading. When I change the heading I just change it's binding property `$scope.parent.activeChild`.

And I have used two scope variables `$scope.heading.fadeOutModel` and `$scope.heading.fadeInModel` to add and remove classes `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` dynamically.

When user clicks to change the heading, I have added the class `fadeOut` to your heading. So, this will show an animation of fade out. And also I have fired a function in app.js, `changeHeading()`.

You can see that, I forced the angular to wait for `1000` milliseconds  to finish fade out animation. After this time, it will replace the selected heading to new one and add a class `fadeIn`. So, it will start animation for fade in.

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but I'm really not looking for a 'workaround' here. I would like to have an example demonstrated that directly uses Angular's animation module to achieve this. 

I should have been clearer in my question. Perhaps if you could provide an answer which does this?

Comment: @EchoLogic, Hmm. I have updated my answer. Not updated my Explanation right now.

Answer (score 4):

A more ng-animate way to show a specific element depending on a selection would be to use `ngSwitch`. This directive is used to conditionally swap DOM structure on your template based on a scope expression. Here is a [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3d8WRCBweqeoocMNuwXO?p=preview).

**HTML**

```
<button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="parent.selection = item">{{ item }}</button>
<div class="animate-switch-container" ng-switch on="parent.selection">
  <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="bar">bar</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.items = ['foo', 'bar'];
$scope.parent = {
  selection: $scope.items[0]
}
```

**CSS**

```
.animate-switch-container {
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.animate-switch {
  padding:10px;

}
.animate-switch.ng-animate {
  transition:opacity 1s ease;

}
.animate-switch.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate-switch.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.animate-switch.ng-leave,
.animate-switch.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This is not chaining, but it is a working animation directly using Angular's ngAnimate module. Also here is a [example of it on angular's website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch#animations).

Comment: had the same problem, this was the perfect solution for me

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.animation` to define animations that are Javascript based. For example, the functions you define as the values of `addClass` and `removeClass`

```
app.animation('.fade', [function() {
    return {
        addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
        },
        removeClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
        }
    };
}]);
```

are called by Angular when it detects that you are adding  or removing a class from an element, from one of the methods:

- `{{ }}` interpoation in a template. E.g. `<span class="{{shouldFade ? 'fade' : ''}}">....`
- Using `ng-class` in a template. E.g. `<span ng-class="{fade: shouldFade}">...`
- Using the `$animate` service in a directive. E.g. `$animate.addClass(element, 'fade')` or `$animate.removeClass(element, 'fade')`

> What is className? Is it the class I want to apply while fading in/out? The class I'm expecting?

In this example it will be `fade`. It a bit strange admittedly as in the example it is already clear this is the class name involved. However, if in the same digest cycle you're adding multiple classes to the same element, then the concatenation of them are passed as this string.

> What is doneFn meant to be? I assume it's a function that's run once the animation is complete? What goes in there?

It's a function that *you* call once whatever Javascript animation you define is done. For example, to define an animation that does nothing as all:

```
addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
  doneFn();
},
```

Calling it tells Angular that the animation has complete. This will, among other things, remove the `ng-animate` class from the element.

> What do I do in the addClass and removeClass function then, if I already have a doneFn?

You put in them some code, perhaps using timeouts or a 3rd party library, to change the element somehow. When you have finished, you call `doneFn`. For example, a 1 step opacity "animation":

```
addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
  element.css('opacity', 0.5);
  setTimeout(function() {
    doneFn();
  }, 1000);
},
```

> I'd like to generate a working animation directly using Angular's ngAnimate module, with either CSS or JS.

This doesn't really have much to do with the answers above! If I were doing a real-case, I strongly suspect I would position the elements absolutely, as anything else (that I can think of) at least, is a bit overly complicated.

However, if you do really want to chain the animations using ngAnimate, one possible way is to use the fact that `$animate.addClass` and `$animate.removeClass` returns a promise when it completes. In order to chain onto the end of such a promise returned when hiding an element, it must be called from some sort of central location, and keep track of which element is visible, being hidden, and being shown.

A way of doing this is to use 2 custom directives. One will be on each element to show and hide, that could be used very much like `ngShow`. The other will be a parent directive that will allow only one element to be visible at any time, and chain removal of the `ng-hide` class (and associated animations) after any addition of `ng-hide`. The directives will have to communicate, could be called something like `ngShowUnique` and `ngShowUniqueController`, such as in the following example.

```
<div ng-show-unique-controller>
  <h1 class="fade" ng-repeat="child in parent.children" ng-show-unique="parent.activeChild == child">@{{child.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

and they could be implemented as below.

```
app.directive('ngShowUniqueController', function($q, $animate) {
  return {
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      var elements = [];
      var expressions = [];
      var watchers = [];
      var unregisterWatchers = null;
      var visibleElement = null;

      function registerWatchers() {
        unregisterWatchers = $scope.$watchGroup(expressions, function(vals) {
          var newCurrentIndex = vals.indexOf(true);
          var addPromise;

          if (visibleElement) {
            // Set a fixed height, as there is a brief interval between
            // removal of this class and addition of another
            $element.css('height', $element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px'); 
            addPromise = $animate.addClass(visibleElement, 'ng-hide');
          } else {
            addPromise = $q.when();
          }
          visibleElement = elements[newCurrentIndex] || null;
          if (!visibleElement) return;

          addPromise.then(function() {
            if (visibleElement) {
              $animate.removeClass(visibleElement, 'ng-hide').then(function() {
                $element.css('height', '');
              });
            }
          })
        });
      }   

      this.register = function(element, expression) {
        if (unregisterWatchers) unregisterWatchers();
        elements.push(element[0]);
        expressions.push(expression);
        registerWatchers();

        // Hide elements initially
        $animate.addClass(element, 'ng-hide');
      };

      this.unregister = function(element) {
        if (unregisterWatchers) unregisterWatchers();
        var index = elements.indexOf(element[0]);
        if (index > -1) {
          elements.splice(index, 1);
          expressions.splice(index, 1);
        }
        registerWatchers();
      };
    } 
  };
});

app.directive('ngShowUnique', function($animate) {
  return {
    require: '^ngShowUniqueController',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngShowUniqueController) {
      ngShowUniqueController.register(element, function() {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.ngShowUnique);
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        ngShowUniqueController.unregister(element);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/1eJUou4UaH6bnAN0nJn7?p=preview . I have to admit, it's all a bit faffy.

Comment: Lots of other good answers (some which are probably better from a best practices standpoint), but you directly answered my question and produced a usable result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

using **ngRepeat that shows only one element** at time, in my opinion, is a bad idea... because you're showing only one element!
you can use the parent.activeChild property directly...

### Have a look on what follows:

Note: I did this snippet in just ten minutes, it's unoptimized and can have some bug... you can use it as starter :)

```js
(function(window, angular, APP) {
  APP
    .value('menuObject', {
      name: 'Main Navigation',
      current: null,
      children: [{
        label: 'Don\'t ng-show element until ng-hide CSS transition is complete?',
        url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336249/dont-ng-show-element-until-ng-hide-css-transition-is-complete',
        isCurrent: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Hitmands - Linkedin',
        url: 'http://it.linkedin.com/in/giuseppemandato',
        isCurrent: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Hitmands - Github',
        url: 'https://github.com/hitmands',
        isCurrent: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Hitmands - StackOverflow',
        url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/4099454/hitmands',
        isCurrent: false
      }
  ]})
  .directive('menu', function(menuObject, $q) {
    function menuCtrl($scope, $element) {
      $scope.parent = menuObject;
      
      this.getCurrentChild = function() {
        return $scope.parent.current;
      };
      this.getDomContext = function() {
        return $element;
      };
      this.setCurrentChild = function(child) {
        return $q.when($scope.parent)
        .then(function(parent) {
          parent.current = child;
          return parent;
        })
        .then(function(parent) {
          return parent.children.forEach(function(item) {
            item.isCurrent = child && (item.label === child.label);
          });
        })
      };
    }
    
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'embedded-menutemplate',
      scope: {},
      controller: menuCtrl
    };
  })
  .directive('menuItem', function($animate, $q, $timeout) {
    
    function menuItemPostLink(iScope, iElement, iAttributes, menuCtrl) {
      iElement.bind('click', setCurrentTitle);
      iScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        iElement.unbind('click', setCurrentTitle);
      })
      
      function setCurrentTitle(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var title;
        
        return $q
        .when(menuCtrl.getDomContext())
        .then(function(_menuElement) {
          title = angular.element(
            _menuElement[0].querySelector('#menuItemCurrent')
          );
        })
        .then(function() {
          return title.addClass('fade-out');
        })
        .then(function() {
          return $timeout(menuCtrl.setCurrentChild, 700, true, iScope.child);
        })
        .then(function() {
          return title.removeClass('fade-out');
        })
      }
    }
    
    return {
      require: '^menu',
      link: menuItemPostLink,
      restrict: 'A'
    };
  })
;

})(window, window.angular, window.angular.module('AngularAnimationExample', ['ngAnimate']));
```

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
 }
 .link {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 1em;
 }
 #menuItemCurrent {
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 #menuItemCurrent span {
  transition: 500ms opacity linear;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 #menuItemCurrent.fade-out span {
  opacity: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>

<article ng-app="AngularAnimationExample">
  
  <nav menu></nav>

  <script id="embedded-menutemplate" type="text/ng-template">

 <nav >
  <a menu-item class="link" ng-repeat="child in parent.children track by $index" ng-bind="child.label"  ng-href="{{ child.url }}"></a>
 
  <h1 id="menuItemCurrent"><span  ng-bind="parent.current.url || 'NoMenuCurrentSelected'"></span></h1> 
  {{ parent.current || json }}
 </nav>
 
  </script>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that H1 is a block level element that is positioned within it's parent and no overlap is allowed.  That is why you see one animation that's disappearing pushing down the animation that is appearing.

You can see that this is happening more clearly here: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DAV5TbJ9G4qJFCh9yZKZ?p=preview)

To fix this, you want to keep the block level element H1, and make its position relative, so that it can keep its relative position in the overall flow of the page.  Then set the child SPAN elements to have absolute positioning - absolute position relative to the parent H1.  This allows all span elements to overlap each other.

**CSS**

```
.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.fade.ng-hide-add {
    transition:opacity 1s ease;
    position: absolute;
}

.fade.ng-hide-remove {
    transition:opacity 1s ease 1s;
    position: absolute;
}

.fade.ng-hide-add {
  opacity:1;
}

.fade.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity:0;
}

.fade.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity:0;
}

.fade.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1><span class="fade" ng-repeat="child in parent.children" ng-show="parent.activeChild == child ">@{{child.title}}</span></h1>
    <button ng-repeat="child in parent.children" ng-click="parent.activeChild = child">{{ child.title }}</button>
  </body>
```

There is one problem though... Since the SPAN elements have absolute positioning, it is removed from flow when animating, and the parent H1 can't resize to fit the SPAN contents.  This causes the SPAN to jump unexpectedly.

The way to address this (and admittedly, it's a bit of a hack) is by adding an empty space after the SPAN repeater. So when the ngRepeat SPANS get pulled out of normal flow because of absolute positioning, the empty space which is outside the ngRepeat preserves the spacing of the H1.

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPZ8FWF1GP2beEFLi1tl?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into transitionend event which is supported by all modern browsers.

```
element.addEventListener('transitionend', callback, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to this - To solve this problem in the past I have always positioned the content absolute.  This way when the transition takes place it stays in the same position.

There is no other way around it because the content takes up space in the dom if its `inline` or `inline-block` which is why you see the jump until the transition is finished