# Animation angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to animate a div on click. When i click on a link a div should be appear and that div i clicked disappear. I made an example here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/703244UJ0hcG9GjkOjOz?p=preview

By the way this is some code:

```
 <a class="" ng-click="showDetails" ng-if="!showDetails">
        Expand 
    </a>


  <div class="animate-if" ng-if="showDetails">

  Details!!
  <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="!showDetails">
      Close
  </a>
  </div>

  {{showDetails}}
</body>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
 showDetails = false;

});
```

css:

```
.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
  -moz-transition: 1s linear all;
  -ms-transition: 1s linear all;
  -o-transition: 1s linear all;
  transition: 1s linear all;
}
.animate-if.ng-enter {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  max-height: 999px;
  opacity:1;
}
.animate-if.ng-leave {
  max-height: 999px;
  opacity:1;
}
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity:1;
}
```

So, when i click "Expand" should be appear the div with class: animate-if and disappear this one:

```
<a class="" ng-click="showDetails" ng-if="!showDetails">
        Expand 
    </a>
```

Then, when i click Close should be disappear the div : animate-if and re-appear the link "Expand" again. Of course using the animation. Actually not working. Not appears or disappears.

Comment: Didn't you forget about including ng-animate.js ? It may be a dumb question but I sometimes forgot it ..

Comment: Nope, the ng-animate.js is already included. I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

You need a toggle function that will toggle the value of `showDetail` variable on click `expand` div.

js :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
 $scope.showDetails = false;
 $scope.toggleDetails =function (){
   $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails; 

 }
});
```

html :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <a class="" ng-if="!showDetails" ng-click="toggleDetails()">
        Expand 
    </a>
  <div class="animate-if" ng-if="showDetails">
    Details!!
  <a style="cursor:pointer;"  ng-click="toggleDetails()">
      Close
  </a>
  </div>
   {{showDetails}}
</body>
```

[**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wCWoLxYrId38G2PDLPu1?p=preview)

Comment: Ok it works now with the function but see here the problem; i added ng-if="!showDetails" in the Expand link. So when i click it disappear and appear the div in correct way.. But when i click over "Close" the "Expand" word appears before the div with "Close" disappear.. This is what i mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/wCWoLxYrId38G2PDLPu1?p=preview

Comment: @End.Game i was mistakenly removed the ng-if directive from expand div. happy for you.. :)

Comment: Is there a way maybe to detect when the animation finish?

Comment: @End.Game check here http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

Comment: Yes i tried to check that link you posted but without success.. Have you idea how can i use it in my situation?

Comment: What i need now is make appear again "Expand" after the animation of  "Close" is finished.. Is it possible?

Comment: check also this..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828681/angularjs-css-animation-done-callback