# Angular JS and Animate.css: fade animation is janky

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I have a dialog in which I'd like to display one of two things depending on the state of a variable.  So, I hooked up 2 versions of a form with ng-if.

When you click "delete" button on first state, it toggles to the second state.

I wanted to make it less abrupt, so I tried adding some css:

```
[ng-if].ng-enter {
  animation: fadeIn .5s;
}
[ng-if].ng-leave {
  animation: fadeOut .5s;
}
```

These animations come from the bower package "animate css":

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
   0% {opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

However, as you can see in my animated GIF below, what happens is that for a second BOTH forms appear, making the dialog taller, then one fades out.

[image: animated gif sample]

Is there no way to do a simple fadein/fadeout as in jQuery? I used to do this all the time with it, but trying to get nice UI animation in Angular is eluding me.

Comment: You're probably looking for callbacks, so you can fade one out, *then* fade the other in -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828681/angularjs-css-animation-done-callback

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an Angular app and animations. I ended up having to use jquery - I wish I had a better answer - but it turned out beautifully. One note, though, I had to wrap any jquery I used in a noConflict() and use body on click plus the element because it doesn't exist yet in the DOM:

```
$.noConflict();jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
      $('body').on('click', "#toggler", function(){
        $('#div_to_show').slideDown();
  });
});
```

I realize this a tangential answer and not an elegant solution but it worked for me to get it out the door under a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution is to change the state you use to check which form is to display when the animation ng-leave ends.

You can use a second variable to set the ng-leave class in the form that will be hidden.

I can't post you some code because i don't know your js and html.