# How to get `callback` from other element animation completion, not from self directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

On click of a element, i am doing the animation to other element (say sibling) how to i get the `callback` from my sibling to `scope` function?

here the code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
    $scope.flag=true;
    $scope.animate = function () {
        $scope.flag = !$scope.flag;
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ufF0FwIUFKKhuuepFzgS?p=preview)

Comment: I seen that already. but that not hearing the callback from other element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$animate` service may be used to handle `enter` and `leave` callbacks.

You have used `ng-if` to show/hide the content in your example but `ng-if` doesn't have any hooks to pass a callback in. So you'll have to write your own directive(say `animated-if`) and provide custom hooks to pass callbacks(`animated-if-leave-callback` and `animated-if-enter-callback`).

To fire an event after ng-leave, use `$animate.leave(element, scope.leaveOnClick)`

The enter one is a bit more complicated to not call the callback on initial loading of the directive.

```
var callback = !oldValue && $scope.animatedIfEnterCallback ? $scope.animatedIfEnterCallback : (function() {});
$animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element, callback);
```

Here's the [enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZMpYr93lN8L77B7qM6n?p=preview)updated plunkr

-[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20836688/1379667)

Comment: Ok. But doing just  a css animation why so complected in agularjs? as  a suggestion what is wrong to use the `jquery` on animation part alone in angular?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using jQuery for animation in angular applications. Infact, the use of jQuery is also mentioned in angular' [site](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12) for rich animations. On the other hand, css animations based on `transitions` and `key-frames` are smoother, lighter and helps avoiding additional dependencies.