# AngularJS - Animating ng-repeat enter one by one

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I use angular and **angular-animate** to animate enter of ng-repeats. 
Thats my html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="chatController">
        <ul ng-repeat="module in CurrentModules" class="timeline">
            <li ng-repeat="message in module.ServerMessages" class="timeline-inverted" animate-on-load>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>{{message}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>                       
        </ul>

        <div align="center" ng-repeat="answer in module.Answers"  animate-on-load>
            <div ng-switch on="answer.IsButton">
                <div ng-switch-when="true" align="center">
                    <button ng-click="Answer($event, answer.Value)" class="send-btn">{{answer.Text}}</button>
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-when="false">
                    <form>
                        <input ng-model="answer.Text">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that `animate-on-load` it's only a directive which allow to stagger animate ng-repeate on page load.

My question - Is it possible to run second ng-repeat after first ng-repeat(and also animations for it) are ended?

Comment: You have one syntax error. You are closing ul tag before div tag.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20836688/1640116